# Random Blank Space HTML5

Tags: html, css, text, formatting, margin

I've looked all through the intranets trying to figure out the solution to my issue, and I haven't found any solution that I haven't already tried.

I have a space on my webpage with 0 code, no margins, no padding, no border, just two elements, separated about 300px by... nothing. There is no code or margins that would cause this to happen. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

A Guide to Meditation

Home

Classes

Blog

About

#### Want to Learn How to Meditate?

Join a class
                
            You've Come to the Right Place!
        
    

    
        
            
                Why Meditate?
                    The quick brown 
                    fox hopped over the slow brown
                    tortoise. The quick brown fox hopped over the slow brown
                    tortoise. The quick brown fox 
                    hopped over the slow brown
                    tortoise. The quick brown fox hopped over the slow brown
                    tortoise. The quick brown fox hopped over the slow brown
                    tortoise. The quick brown fox hopped over the slow brown
                    tortoise.
                

            
            
                    
                        The quick brown fox hopped over the slow brown
                        tortoise. The quick brown fox hopped over the slow brown
                        tortoise. The quick brown fox hopped over the slow brown
                        tortoise. The quick brown fox hopped over the slow brown
                        tortoise. The quick brown fox hopped over the slow brown
                        tortoise. The quick brown fox hopped over the slow brown
                        tortoise.

```
* {
padding-left: 0;
border-left: 0;
margin-left: 0; 
margin-right: 0;
padding-right: 0;
border-right: 0;
}

html, body, header, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, img, ol, ul, li, form, label, table, caption, tbody,tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;    
}

.html {
    font-size: 100%; 
    background: url('assets/background.png') no-repeat center fixed; 
    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

@media (max-width: 350px) {

}

.head {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nav {
    position: fixed;
    max-height: 10%;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFAD5C , #FF9933);
    border-right: none;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav ul {
    float: inherit;
    top: 10px;
    height: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    width: 16.6667%; /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
    width: calc(100% / 5);
    height: 75px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav li:hover {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color;
    transition-property: color, background-color;
    background: #FF7F47;
}

.hvr-fade:focus, .hvr-fade:active {
    background-color: #2098d1;
    color: white;
    background: #FF7F47;
    -webkit-animation: pulsate 1.2s linear infinite;
}

#nav li a {
    display: inherit;
    font-family: 'Roboto' serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 12px 0;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

/*jumbotron*/ /*jumbotron*/ /*jumbotron*/ /*jumbotron*/ /*jumbotron*/ 

.jumbotron {
    display: flex;
    background-image: url('assets/meditate.jpg');
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 80px;
}

.jumbotron button {
    position: inherit;
    top: 50%;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    color: #FFF;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFAD5C, #FF9933);
    background: linear-gradient(#FFAD5C, #FF9933);
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #666, 0 5px 0 #444, 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
    transition: all 150ms ease;
}

.jumbotron button:hover, button:focus
{
    -webkit-animation: pulsate 1.2s linear infinite;
    animation: pulsate 1.2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate
{
    0%   { color: #ddd; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000; }
    50%  { color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #444, 
    0 0 5px #ffd, 0 0 8px #fff; }
    100% { color: #ddd; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000; }
}

@keyframes pulsate
{
    0%   { color: #ddd; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000; }
    50%  { color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #444, 
    0 0 5px #ffd, 0 0 8px #fff; }
    100% { color: #ddd; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000; }
}

button:active {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #444, 0 0 5px #ffd, 0 0 8px #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #666, 0 2px 0 #444, 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(3px);
    transform: translateY(3px);
    -webkit-animation: none;
    animation: none;
}

.jumbotron a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/*body*/ /*body*/ /*body*/ /*body*/ /*body*/ /*body*/

.body {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 1%;
}

.bodyflex1 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    padding-top: 0px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin: 1%;
}

/*column1*/ /*column1*/ /*column1*/ /*column1*/ /*column1*/

.column1 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 2;      
    -moz-box-flex: 2;         
    -webkit-flex: 2;          
    -ms-flex: 2;              
    flex: 2;
    padding: 2%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin: 1%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 4px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 4px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 4px #ccc;
}

.flextable {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 2%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.flexlist {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 2.7em;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding: 2%;
}

/*column2*/ /*column2*/ /*column2*/ /*column2*/ /*column2*/

.column2 {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 1.0000001%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 4px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 4px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 4px #ccc;
}

.cssad {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2%;
}

/*font*/ /*font*/ /*font*/ /*font*/ /*font*/ /*font*/ /*font*/ 

.jumbotron h3, h4 {
    color: #FFFFFF; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #444, 0 0 5px #ffd, 0 0 5px #000;
    text-align: center;
    position: inherit;
    font-size: 2.4em;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
} 

.orange {
    font-size: 3em;
    color: orange;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #ccc;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 10;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    line-height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.bodyp {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 10;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    line-height: 100%;
    white-space: -pre-wrap;
}

.bodyp1 {
   margin-top: -250px;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    line-height: 100%;
    white-space: -pre-wrap;
}
@media all and (max-width: )
```

Instead of using html, head and body tags I used an unordered list in hopes of getting flexbox to work properly, this could be a possible reason for it not working. I also attempted to place a comment in-between the heading3 and paragraph elements, but that obviously didn't work.

I'm using the Cloud9 (c9.io) code editor. In the CSS, I tried putting a negative value of margin-top, that did not work consistently either. When I open code inspector from Google Chrome, it shows my heading3 and paragraph elements with nothing in-between and no margins, padding, or borders preventing the heading3 and paragraph being closer together. I'm really lost.

Let me know if you need a link to view all of my code or if you need any more information. This is my first post here as usually I can figure things out on my own but in this case I seem to have come across an impossible scenario. Feel free to also let me know if there is anything I can do to improve my code if you have time.

EDIT: I already set margin and padding to 0. It didn't work. Inspect element showed that there was 0 margin or padding in my p and h3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Default h1 and p tag take extra margin at top and bottom. You can remove it like:

```
h3{
    margin:0;
}
p
{
    margin:0;
}
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xtb1k4wj/)

Comment: I already tried this and it didn't work. Google Chrome inspect element even shows 0 margin and padding on my h3 and p elements.

Comment: @DaltonHaberman Have you checked my fiddle in chrome? Here it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I found it most useful to reset all margin, padding and borders before starting your normal CSS. Easiest thing is to put this code at the start of all CSS files

```
html, body, header, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, img, ol, ul, li, form, label, table, caption, tbody,tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;    
}
```

If that doesn't work please provide your CSS so we can take a look.

P.S I don't think that using

is a good practice here. Use normal tags and if you need to group text you can use  and .

P.S2 Think about using "id" instead of "class" if this is an element that is used only once.

Comment: I thought that worked, but it only works at a certain width. Somehow when I make the p element text wider it moves up towards the heading. When I make it smaller it moves down. Any suggestions? I'll put all of my html and css in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, its simple. All browsers have their own interpretation of default details of "margins", "paddings", "borders", etc. Therefore, before beginning any new project you must add the following code to your css:

```
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
```

Now, write your code. You wont find any spaces without your consent anywhere! Happy Coding!

Comment: I already tried this with the universal selector and it didn't work. Google Chrome inspect element even shows 0 margin and padding on my h3 and p elements.